# RegEx ignore text inside inner braces .net

Tags: .net, regex

I have requirement where I have to handle `NOT`. For example:

`NOT( A AND B)` will be converted to
`NOT A OR NOT B`

Now my problem is if there is a bracket inside it should just skip it as is.
For example:

`NOT( A AND B or (C AND D) )`
will be converted to
`NOT A OR NOT B AND NOT(C AND D)`

Note `(C AND D)` is left untouched
I am using following regex:

```
(?<PRE>[ ]\bnot\b\()(?<IN>\b.*?\b)(?<POST>\))
```

Comment: Please read the editor help and make your question readable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you simply use (note the missing question mark):

```
(?<PRE>[ ]\bnot\b\()(?<IN>\b.*\b)(?<POST>\))
```

then the `.*` will match as many characters as possible and so the `\)` will match the last `)` of the expression.